# change maxlength depending of the option selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've seen similar questions posted and tried to change them to meet my needs but I don't know enough about javascript to do it.
I need that when a user change the dropdown select, the "titre text field" maxlength is dynamically changed

a, b c and d max maxlength should be 40
and maxlength should be 2

my code is below, I don't know why but it is not working correctly. when i change the selection option to "E", the maxLength of the titre input box is the default value (40), not 2. This is the problem. It should be 2.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>title page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeValue(dropdown) {
        var option = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value,
            field = document.getElementById('titre');

        if (option == 'a' || option == 'b' || option == 'c' || option == 'd') {
          field.maxLength = 40;
        } else if (option == 'e') {
          field.value = field.value.substr(0, 2); // before reducing the maxlength, make sure it contains at most two characters; you could also reset the value altogether
          field.maxLength = 2;
        }
      }?
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="converter.php" method="post">
      <h2>Feel all field below:</h2>
      <div>
        Title: <input type="texte" name="titre" id="titre" maxLength="40"/>  Format: 
        <select id="format" name="format" onchange="changeValue(this);">
          <option value="a">A</option>
          <option value="b">B</option>
          <option value="c">C</option>
          <option value="d">D</option>
          <option value="e">E</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea name="texte" style="width: 415px; height: 155px;"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly means `not working correctly`? Your code works as it is in IE10, FF, Opera and Chrome. What you expect it to do? Though there's an extra questionmark just before `</script>`, maybe a typo in the post? What browser do you use?

Comment: when i change the selection option to "E", the maxLength of the titre input box is the default value (40), not 2. This is the problem.

Comment: Yup, only that typo is wrong. Otherwise all looks correct - here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/HbShf/

Comment: @jfrej actually jsfiddle seems not to be working correctly. At least not for me. Maybe an inline js problem?

Comment: @mkey, here is working in firefox and chrome

Comment: @tuner3000 yes, as it seems noscript is blocking that site so some functionality is interpreted as a xss attack. All fixed now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a questionmark at the end of the function definition.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>title page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeValue(dropdown) {
                var option = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value,
                field = document.getElementById('titre');

                if (option == 'e') {
                    field.value = field.value.substr(0, 2); // before reducing the maxlength, make sure it contains at most two characters; you could also reset the value altogether
                    field.maxLength = 2;
                } else {
                    field.maxLength = 40;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="converter.php" method="post">
            <h2>Feel all field below:</h2>
            <div>
                Title: <input type="texte" name="titre" id="titre" maxLength="40"/>  Format: 
                <select id="format" name="format" onchange="changeValue(this);">
                    <option value="a">A</option>
                    <option value="b">B</option>
                    <option value="c">C</option>
                    <option value="d">D</option>
                    <option value="e">E</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea name="texte" style="width: 415px; height: 155px;"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                <input type="submit" value="OK" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now there's an extra semicolon ; ).